# SQL Server query - Field B Contains Field A data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with FieldA and FieldB. How can find the records in which Field A values are in Field B ?

```
Field A                   Field B
123                       Main 123
567                       567 Elm Street
Oak                       123 Oak Lane
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Using [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select st.* 
 from SomeTable st
      join SomeTable stt on st.FieldB like '%'+stt.FieldA+'%';
```

Or (if only within row comparison is needed)

```
select * 
from SomeTable
where FieldB like '%'+FieldA+'%';
```

Comment: I'm not sure this even needs a self join.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe so.  Yes it could be simplified